# How do I run my flutter program on the Android emulator ? Because when it runs the program can only run on Chrome

Tags: flutter, dart

I installed the flutter and dart plugins on Android Studio, already installed SDK and AVD for the Android emulator. But the program still runs on chrome

Comment: are you using vscode? If yes in the bottom right there's chrome written. Click on it and select the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using VS Code, you can select the target device by using the status bar changer:

[image]

That will open up the list of connected devices in the command palette you can pick from.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To see available emulators run this command:

```
flutter emulators
```

Then copy the name of emulator from there and enter this command:

```
flutter emulators --launch EmulatorNameHere
```

Now when the emulator ready and running:

```
flutter run
```

Answer (score 1):

Launch your Android emulator, run `flutter devices` to get the id of the emulator device. Then, you can run `flutter run -d [emulator_id]` to launch the Flutter application on the targeted device.